Oracle SQL Insert Trigger to Handle Duplicate Contacts and Update Owner Field
I have a Oracle SQL table named CONTACTS with the columns ID, NAME, PHONE, OWNER.
ID is Primary Key, Phone and (Name, Phone) are unique.
I have a insert query for this table :
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO CONTACTS (NAME, PHONE, OWNER)
    VALUES (:P170_NAME, :P170_PHONE, :APP_USER);
END;

And in front-end, I am trying to create a trigger for those situations below:

When someone tries to create a new contact with a new phone, it can be created, all is fine
When someone tries to create a new contact that is already created by another user which is also unique due to (name, phone), update the owner column of that phone number and store both owners separating with comma, here is an example:

If ('Mustafa Turhan', '905554443322', 'M.TURHAN') is already created
and someone tries to create ('Mustafa Turhan', '905554443322', 'K.AKKUS'), it should do this: ('1','Mustafa Turhan', '905554443322', 'M.TURHAN,K.AKKUS')

When someone tries to create ('Alihan Turhan', '905554443322', 'K.CEKIC') it should throw an error because 'phone' is unique.


What have you tried so far?

Don't store data in comma-delimited strings.

i have tried creating a insert trigger which checks if that phone already exists. if yes, it would make an update.
then i got error because i cant run an update query inside an insert query??

If you can have mutliple OWNERs then store the values in a separate table. Do NOT store muliple values in a comma-delimited string.
CREATE SEQUENCE contacts__id__seq;
CREATE SEQUENCE contact_owners__id__seq;

CREATE TABLE contacts (
  id    NUMBER
        DEFAULT contacts__id__seq.NEXTVAL
        CONSTRAINT contacts__id__pk PRIMARY KEY,
  name  VARCHAR2(50)
        NOT NULL,
  phone VARCHAR2(20)
        CONSTRAINT contacts__phone__u UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE contact_owners (
  id         NUMBER
             DEFAULT contact_owners__id__seq.NEXTVAL
             CONSTRAINT contact_owners__id__pk PRIMARY KEY,
  contact_id NOT NULL
             CONSTRAINT contact_owners__cid__fk REFERENCES contacts(id),
  owner      VARCHAR2(20)
             NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT contact_owners__cid__o__u UNIQUE (contact_id, owner)
);

Then when you want to insert a value you can use:
DECLARE
  v_id    CONTACTS.ID%TYPE;
BEGIN
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO contacts (id, name, phone)
    VALUES (DEFAULT, :P170_NAME, :P170_PHONE)
    RETURNING id INTO v_id;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
      BEGIN
        SELECT id
        INTO   v_id
        FROM   contacts
        WHERE  phone = :P170_PHONE
        AND    name  = :P170_NAME;

        GOTO skip_raise_error;
      EXCEPTION
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
          NULL;
          -- Fall through and raise the previous error.
      END;
      RAISE;
  END;

  <<skip_raise_error>>
  MERGE INTO contact_owners dst
  USING DUAL
  ON (v_id = dst.contact_id AND :APP_USER = dst.owner)
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (id, contact_id, owner) VALUES (DEFAULT, v_id, :APP_USER);
END;
/

fiddle

just asking to learn, what does the "merge into" query do here? thanks

@Zolomon Checks if the contact_id/owner pair is already in the table and, if not, inserts it into the table (preventing inserting duplicates). I would have used MERGE for the first part as well but it does not support the RETURNING INTO clause necessary to return the new id value so had to use an INSERT statement there.

i used the same contact informations (same name, same phone) with a different user, it inserted the same contact to the contacts table and it also inserted a row to the contacts_owner table with the new id created

@Zolomon Are you sure you used exactly the same name and phone? I cannot replicate the issue if they are exactly the same but if you put a space at the end of the phone number then they are different fiddle

A trigger is not the way to implement any of these requirements. From your question, it seems you're using Oracle APEX. Here is how this is usually done in APEX:
Create a validation for the phone number uniqueness (requirement 3).
Requirement 2: Instead of a simple insert, create a pl/sql block that checks if the phone number is unique. If it is unique, insert the rows, if it is not unique then update the existing row.
Note, as @MTO mentioned in the comments, strong comma separated data is not a good practice and should be avoided.

The OP does not mention Oracle Apex in the question. There are plenty of "front-ends" that can be used to talk to an Oracle database that are not Oracle Apex.

so how can i store those multiple owners except commas, any suggestions?

@MTO true and agree, but the Pnnn_COLUMN_NAME is the advised Oracle APEX naming convention for page items, I'd be suprised if it is anything else.

@Zolomon, you'd have a child table for contacts, referencing CONTACTS with a foreign key. That table would have one row per user who touches this record

so, for example, second table will be like (id, contact_id, owner)
and every owner will hold a row, so if a contact has 3 owners, it will hold 3 rows,
am i correct?

correct. Check answer from @MTO he worked out a complete example
